# Is there any way to minify this code further?

Tags: python, python-3.x, minify

Here I have a block of python script. It's a simple guessing game. I was wondering, how far can I boil this down? Are there any more tricks that I can employ to remove some extraneous code, aside from importing modules?

```
from random import randint
n = randint(1,20)
print("I'm thinking of a number 1-20. Keep guessing until you get it!")
while True:
    try:
        g = int(input(""))
    except(ValueError):
        print("INPUT MUST BE AN INTEGER!")
    else:
        if g == n:
            print("YOU WIN!")
            exit()
        if g > n:
            print("Too high!")
        else:
            print("Too low!")
```

Comment: What extraneous code? I don't see any.

Comment: Why would you want to make this code shorter?

Comment: @Aran-Fey  it's out of curiosity. There's no code that's extraneous, as far as I am aware, though I'm certain something could be done to further reduce its size. I'm interested in minification.

Comment: Changing `exit()` to `break` saves 1 character, changing `(ValueError)` to ` ValueError` saves another. Removing unnecessary spaces around operators saves 8. Indenting with a single space instead of 4 saves a lot. Downgrading to python 2 lets you omit the parentheses for the `print`s but requires `raw_input` instead of `input`, so that's a net reduction of another 6 characters.

Comment: There is (almost) always a way to make code shorter, but shorter is not always better. This seems to be optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks OK. You can't really make it much shorter, but a little more readable with a `get_number` function that handles getting user input. In addition, instead of using `exit` you could just `break` your loop.

Once [Assignment Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) hit with Python 3.8, you can even get rid of that `break`:

```
from random import randint

def get_number():
    'ask for an integer until user provides an integer'
    while True:
        try:
            g = int(input('enter integer: '))
            return g
        except ValueError:
            print('INPUT MUST BE AN INTEGER!')

secret = random.randint(1, 20)
while (g := get_number()) != secret:
    if g > n:
        print('too high!')
    else:
        print('too low!')

print('YOU WIN!')
```